# How to add text at the end of df in pandas when export df to Excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have got some several df in pandas and I export them to excel like this:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('result.xlsx') as writer:
    df_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='one')
    df_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='two')
```

And I would like to add some text at the end of df in the same sheet 'one', e.g. `text1 = 'Done'`
This one does not work:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('result.xlsx') as writer:
    df_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='one')
    df_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='two')
    text1.to_excel(writer, startrow=20, sheet_name='one')
```

And I cannot figure out correct syntax. Would you please help me?
P.S. I can calculate correct `startrow` in advance to not overwrite df data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a row in the end of `df` and add Done to one of the column by making others zero. For example, lets assume you have four columns

```
new_row = {'col1': '', 'col2': 'Done', 'col3': '', 'col4': ''}
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```